# How would I positionally select records based on a desired value (using SparkSQL)?

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I had the following table:

```
+------+------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | NumCol |
+------+------+--------+
| a    | z    |      1 |
| b    | y    |      2 |
| c    | x    |      3 |
| d    | w    |      0 |
| e    | v    |      4 |
| f    | u    |      5 |
| g    | t    |      0 |
| h    | s    |      6 |
| i    | r    |      0 |
+------+------+--------+
```

So I would like to go through all of the records. Every time I find the value 0 in NumCol, I want to select that record and every record that came before it, up to the precious occurence of the value 0. So for I should return something like this (if looped through the whole table):

```
+------+------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | NumCol |
+------+------+--------+
| a    | z    |      1 |
| b    | y    |      2 |
| c    | x    |      3 |
| d    | w    |      0 |
+------+------+--------+
```

```
+------+------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | NumCol |
+------+------+--------+
| e    | v    |      4 |
| f    | u    |      5 |
| g    | t    |      0 |
+------+------+--------+
```

```
+------+------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | NumCol |
+------+------+--------+
| h    | s    |      6 |
| i    | r    |      0 |
+------+------+--------+
```

Comment: What database you are using `sql server`, `MySql`, or? Also do you have any `Id` column in table?

Comment: You are talking about previous rows. By what order? By column `a`? Then, you are showing three results. A query has one result. If I combine the three results you are showing, it's just the whole table, but I guess you are not looking for `select * from mytable order by a`?! Do you want just one of the three results? How then, do you know which?

Comment: @Karan I am using Spark SQL. This would be used to aggregate the selected data into a single record for a different table. This is on Google Cloud. And there is nothing like id, though it’s possible to add that beforehand.

Comment: Maybe what you are not asking is not want you really *want*  to ask. Do you really want the table split into multiple results or do you rather want an aggregation of the table, i.e a result set consisting of rows holding sums, counts and the like?

Answer (score 0):

What i would recommend is to use "Cursor" if you are using Microsoft -SQL.
Using cursor you can loop through records one by one and cut it off once it reaches zero.
You probably want to create a table separate to the one you have listed which you can feed from the cursor as it will speed up things.
if you will try to do all this in memory it may struggle.

Answer (score 0):

First, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  I am going to assume that the first two columns specify the ordering.

You can enumerate the groups using a cumulative sum -- by adding the number of `0` on or after each row.  Then to get a value starting at zero, you can subtract from the total number of zeros:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             (sum(case when num_col = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over () + 1 -
              sum(case when numcol = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by col1 desc, col2 desc)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can now select groups of rows by just using `where grp = N`.